# linq сортировка списка по булевым полям

Tags: c#, сортировка, linq

Имеется тестовый класс:

```
public class TestData
{
    public bool IsImportant { get; set; }
    public bool IsImportant1 { get; set; }
    public bool IsImportant2 { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

P.S заранее прошу не придираться к неймингу )

Я создаю список объектов TestData , и мне нужно сортировать по полям IsImportant или IsImportant1 или IsImportant2

```
 // Add data to the list.
var items = new List<TestData>();
items.Add(new TestData() { IsImportant = true, Data = "Bird" });
items.Add(new TestData() { IsImportant1 = true, Data = "Cat" });
items.Add(new TestData() { IsImportant2 = true, Data = "Human" });

// Sort by bool on class.
var sorted = items.OrderBy(x => x.IsImportant1).ToArray();

// Put "important" items first.
foreach (var item in sorted)
{
    Console.WriteLine( $"{ item.Data} ; {item.IsImportant}; {item.IsImportant1}; { item.IsImportant2}");
}
```

Результат вывода :

```
Bird ; True; False; False
Human ; False; False; True
Cat ; False; True; False
```

Вопрос , почему не сортирует по полю IsImportant1? По идее первым должен быть Cat ?
Как сделать так чтобы первым в списке выводился Cat. Просто у меня есть метод который будет в зависимости от параметра сортировать по определенному полю список объектов и выводить его.

Comment: `var sorted = items.OrderByDescending(x => x.IsImportant1).ToArray();` ?

Comment: Спасибо tym32167, Помогло. А почему так работает? интересно может кто-нибудь пояснить? Просто мне нужно будеть делать сортировку по возрастанию и убыванию для каждого поля.

Comment: потому что при сортировке по bool по возрастанию, сначала идут поля с true, а поом с false, что у вас и наблюдается в коде и выводе. Если вам надо гарантиировать, чтобы Cat был всегда первым, вам надо как то по другому сортировать, потому что у Cat и Human у обоих стоит false, потому они могут быть в любом порядке относительно друг друга

Comment: ну и если вы в свой код загляните, вы увидите, что вы соритруете только по одному полю `IsImportant1`, остальные поля просто для красоты, они не участвуют в сортировке.

Comment: @tym32167 наоборот, при сортировке булевого типа по возрастанию значения False будут идти раньше значений True. Что и наблюдается в результате вывода кода у автора вопроса :)

Comment: @MaxS о, да, мой косяк, false->true. Ну, надеюсь, что хотя бы остальное по делу написал 

Comment: Просто false => 0, true => 1, поэтому такая сортировка. `Convert.ToInt32(false)` даст `0`, `Convert.ToInt32(true)` даст `1`.

Comment: @CrazyElf я в курсе, я попутел не от незнания, а он невниматнльности, поглядел в выводе на первый столбик true;false;false и почему то это меня не смутило =)

Comment: @tym32167 Да я в общем-то автору вопроса хотел пояснить, просто его нельзя затэгать в комментарии )  У вас то понятно, что просто описка получилась )

Answer (score 2):

Интерфейс [`IComparable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.icomparable?view=net-6.0) для булевого типа реализован так, что значение `False` *меньше* (дословно – "в порядке сортировки находится до") `True`. [Исходный код структуры `Boolean`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/boolean.cs):

> ```
> public int CompareTo(Boolean value) {
>     if (m_value==value) {
>         return 0;
>     } else if (m_value==false) {
>         return -1;
>     }
>     return 1;    
> }
> ```

Поэтому в вашем примере Cat идет последним – значение его свойства `IsImportant1`, по которому вы проводите сортировку, равно `True`.

Если вам нужно изменить поведение на противоположное – можно вместо

```
var sorted = items.OrderBy(x => x.IsImportant1).ToArray();
```

написать:

```
var sorted = items.OrderByDescending(x => x.IsImportant1).ToArray();
```

Также, можете раскрыть выборку ключа сортировки более явно для себя, например так:

```
items.OrderBy(x => x.IsImportant1 == false ? 0 : 1); // False будут идти раньше True
items.OrderBy(x => x.IsImportant1 == true ? 0 : 1); // True будут идти раньше False
```